# Is there a name for the curve traced by the midpoint of two moving points on a circle with different speed?

Tags: terminology, curves, parametric

I'm curious about what I did in Geogebra while I was experimenting with animation. Here it is:

1. Construct a circle with radius $r$
2. Define two points $A(r\cos a\theta , r \sin a\theta)$ and $B(r\cos b\theta, r \sin b\theta)$. Let $(r,0)$ be the initial position of both $A$ and $B$.
3. Get the midpoint of $AB$. Name this point $M$.
4. Change $\theta$ continuously starting from $0$ until $A$ and $B$ are both at $(r,0)$ again.

The midpoint, by doing the fourth step, seem to make some form of curve. I noticed that the curved traced by the midpoint does not change as long as $a/b$ does not change, even if $a$ and $b$ does so. Also, it doesn't matter if the values of $a$ and $b$ are swapped, but to avoid such ambiguities, we will avoid swapping of values and $a$ is always greater than $b$.

For the file, see [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s6kie2ib7s) graph in Desmos.

For the angle, let $p$ be the numerator of $a/b$ in lowest terms. Then, we have $0 \leq \theta \leq 2p\pi$. (I don't know how to this in Desmos, by the way)

---

### Examples

For $a = 2.1$ and $b = 1.4$,  [image]

For $a = 3$ and $b = 1$, [image]

And for $a = 1.1$ and $b = 0.007$ $(0 \leq \theta \leq 98\pi)$, [image]

As for the midpoint, the coordinates is $$\left(\frac{r}{2}\left(\cos(a\theta) + \cos(b\theta)\right), \frac{r}{2}\left(\sin(a\theta) + \sin(b\theta)\right)\right)$$

This means that the parametric equation is
\begin{align*}
    x(\theta) &= \frac{r}{2}\left(\cos(a\theta) + \cos(b\theta)\right) \\[10pt]
    y(\theta) &= \frac{r}{2}\left(\sin(a\theta) + \sin(b\theta)\right)
\end{align*}
Is there a name for these curves?

---

Update 1: It seems like this is somehow related to the [mathematical basis of a spirograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph#Mathematical_basis).

> ... and therefore the trajectory equations take the form
> \begin{align*} x(t) &= R\left[(1-k)\cos t+lk\cos {\frac{1-k}{k}}t\right],\\y(t)&=R\left[(1-k)\sin t-lk\sin {\frac {1-k}{k}}t\right]\end{align*}

Comment: It looks like what they call the evolute of a cardioid in this page (second figure) https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/largeur%20constante/largeur%20constante.shtml

Comment: Depending on a and b the curves can take many forms with multiple loops (b=1, a = 3) or spirals (a=2.3, b=2) so not cardioid, though one may be a special case.

Comment: This has the properties of several of the so-called transcendental curves, such as the sinusoidal spirals, Archimedean spiral, involute of a circle, and cochleoid. Curves are defined by equations, Cartesian and polar. You need to express this curve as an equation in order to define it, rather than a set of instructions. My go-to reference for plane curves is *A Catalog of Special Plane Curves*, by J. Dennis Lawrence, Dover Publications, 1972.

Comment: @CyeWaldman The parametric equation can be found before Update 1.

Comment: @soupless Thank you. From those equations, I would conclude that this is an unnamed curve. On a quick search the closest curve I can find to this is the hypotrochoid, described by $x=n\cos t+h\cos(n/b\cdot t)$ and $y=n\sin t-h\sin(n/b\cdot t)$.

Comment: I think you meant to say "...until $A$ and $B$ are at $(r,0)$ again." But this will never happen if $a/b$ is irrational. And to answer your deleted comment, this doesn't imply that the curve passes through all points inside the circle. For instance, for any given $s<r$ the curve touches the circle with radius $s$ at only a countable number of points, because each time the curve circumnavigates the origin, it touches such a circle only a finite number of times.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I meant to say "... until $A$ and $B$ are at $(r,0)$ again." Thank you.

Comment: The original curve (mid point of two points on same circle) is the [rhodenea](https://www.2dcurves.com/roulette/rouletter.html#rose), also called the [rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)) or rosette.

Comment: @achillehui Can I ask you to make that as an answer and prove that they are, indeed, the same?

Answer (score 3):

*I am posting this since my updates that can answer my question should be posted as an answer, not as a part of the question.*

---

We restrict the values of $a$ and $b$ to be integers where $a$ and $b$ are both nonzero. Then, the curve seems to represent an epitrochoid given by the parametric equation
\begin{align*}
    x(t) &= m \cos t - h \cos\left(\frac{mt}{c}\right) \\
    y(t) &= m \sin t - h \sin\left(\frac{mt}{c}\right).
\end{align*}

where $m = 1$, $h = 1$, and $c = \frac{a}{b}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2a\pi$.. For the parametric equation in the question, we let $r = 2$.

We can say that the two curves **match** if they are in the same magnitude and angle, and that they **don't match** if they don't have the same angle and magnitude. However, we'll say that they are a **pseudomatch** if they have the same magnitude but not having the same angle.

Now, for odd $a$, the two curve are a pseudomatch regardless of the value of $b$. For even $a$, there are two cases:

1. If $a$ is a power of $2$, then the curves are a pseudomatch if $b$ is a multiple of $a$. Otherwise, the curves are a match.
2. If $a$ is not a power of $2$, then the curves are a pseudomatch if $b$ is a multiple of the greatest power of $2$ that divides $a$. An example would be $a = 28$, where the curves are a pseudomatch if $b$ is a multiple of $4$.

---

As of the moment, I don't know how to prove that this works. I am just relying on graphs from the file.